# Solving a very particular 2 variable recursion relation

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, recursion

While solving a problem, me and a friend hit upon a particular recurrence relation that we tried solving using generating functions but failed. The relation looks like this :

$$P(n,k)=pP(n-1,k+1)+qP(n-1,k-1)$$ with the conditions

$$n\in\mathbb N\cup \{0\},\ 0\le k\le m$$

$$P(n,0)=0,\ P(0,k)=\begin{cases}0\ \ \text{if $k<m$}\\ 1\ \ \text{if $k=m$} \end{cases}$$

$$P(n,k)=0, \text{when $k>m$ or $n<0$}$$

where $m\in\mathbb N$ is a given value.

Here's what we tried. Let us look at a generating function $P(x,y)=\sum_{n,k}P(m,n)x^ny^k$ that models the recursion. Then, we note that:

\begin{multline}P(x,y)(y-px-qxy^2)=\sum_{n,k}P(n,k)(x^ny^{k+1}-px^{n+1}y^k-qx^{n+1}y^{k+2})\\ \hspace{10em}=\sum_{\substack{n\ge 1\\ k\ge 2}}P(n,k-1)-pP(n-1,k)-qP(n-1,k-2)\\ \hspace{7em}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty P(n,1)(x^ny^2-px^{n+1}y-qx^{n+1}y^3)\hspace{2em}+(y^{m+1}-pxy^m-qxy^{m+2})\end{multline}

The first summation vanishes dues to the recurrence relation, and thus we get:

\begin{multline}P(x,y)(y-px-qxy^2)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty P(n,1)(x^ny^2-px^{n+1}y-qx^{n+1}y^3)\\+(y^{m+1}-pxy^m-qxy^{m+2})\end{multline}

But after this, we are stuck.

Any help with solving this is greatly appreciated.

**Edit** : As lonza leggiera points out, the boundary conditions are contradictory to the fact that $p,q\ne 0$. We found out where we went wrong. The correct recursion should be:

$$P(n,k)=pP(n-1,k+1)+qP(n-1,k-1)$$ with the conditions

$$p+q=1$$
$$P(n,k)=0,\ \text{if $n<0$ or $k\le 0$}$$
$$P(0,k)=0,\ \text{if $k< m$}$$
$$P(n,k)=1,\ \text{if $k\ge m$}$$

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: How are you treating $P(n, m)$? You can't calculate it via the recursion, since $P(n, m+1)$ isn't defined.

Comment: @ConMan Right, that's true. I thought it was implicit in the definition of $k$ that $P(n,k)=0$ when $k>m$.

Comment: It isn't, because your definition of $k$ is that it only exists between $0$ and $m$. Things that aren't defined don't automatically equal zero, they just don't exist and you can't reference them. If you want to make it clearer, it would be better to define the recursion as being for $0 < k < m$ and then explicitly make $P(n, m) = pP(n-1,m-1)$.

Comment: @ConMan Ah that makes sense. I will add that to the list of conditions, thanks!

Comment: In which context did the recursion arise?

Comment: @IMOPUTFIE In a problem related to a gambler's ruin

Comment: Mind adding the problem itself for context?

Comment: Does that mean that $\ p+q=1\ $?

Comment: I suggest trying to solve it for $m=2$ first. Then $m=3$. Then you can see the trend.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera Yes, $p+q=1$ in our problem, but we were looking for a more general solution for any $p,q$ because then the techniques might be applicable in a more general setting.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really an answer, but a demonstration that your currently specified conditions are probably not quite what you want.   First, the specifications

> with the conditions
> $$
>  n\color{red}{\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}}, 0\le k\color{red}{\le m}
>  $$

and

> $$
>   P(n,k)=0,\ \text{when }\ \color{red}{k>m}\ \text{or}\ \color{red}{n<0}
> $$

are contradictory. If you ignore the red parts of the first set of conditions and impose just the second set, then I believe a solution will only exist if $\ p=q=0\ $, when the (unique) solution is $\ P(n,k)=0\ $.   From the condition
$$
P(n,k)=0\ \ \text{when }\ k>m\ ,
$$
for example, we get
$$
P(0,m+2)=P(0,m+1)=P(1,m+1)=0
$$
The recursion relation then gives us
$$
P(1,m+1)=pP(0,m+2)+qP(0,m)=q\ ,
$$
from which it follows that $\ q=0\ $.  Showing that $\ p=0\ $ requires a little more work, which I won't bother doing here.

If you instead limit the domain of the solution you're looking for to be integers satisfying
$$
n\ge0, 0\le k\le m+1\ ,
$$
and simply require $ P(n,m+1)=P(n,0)=0\ $ for all $\ n\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}\ $, then I believe there will always be a non-trivial unique solution for which you may be able to obtain a fairly simple expression in closed form.  I'm not inclined to bother trying to find it, however, unless you can say definitely that it really is the solution you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. We realised we made a slight error, and you beautifully pointed out where. We have added an edit. Sorry about the issues.